# Laravel if statement not displaying properly

Tags: php, if-statement, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to get content to show if a variable contains a value and to not show if it is empty.

the if (Isset($section)) works perfectly however the other if statements eithes display all or none, which is not supposed to happen. I have about 3 rows that have a value for $link2 and $link3 and 3 that are empty so want those that are empty hidden.

In php I used the below which worked fine but not sure how to translate this into the laravel @if

```
if ($link3 == ""){
echo "";
}
else {
echo"<div></div>";
}
```

Thanks in advance!

LinkController.php

```
class LinkController extends BaseController {

public function ShowAll() {
$links = Link::orderBy('id')->get();

return View::make('pages.links')
       ->with('links', $links);
```

links.blade.php

```
<div class="links-wrap">
<div class="links-center-wrap">
@foreach ($links as $link)
<div class="links-wrap-wrap">
@if(isset($section)) 

@else
<div class="links-section-header">{{ $link->section }}</div>
@endif
@if(isset($link1)) 

@else
<div class="links-cats-wrap">
<div class="links-cats-img"><img src="images/links/{{ $link->img1 }}"> </div>
<div class="links-cats-link">{{ $link->link1 }}</div>
<div class="links-cats-desc">{{ $link->desc1 }}</div>
</div>
@endif

@if(isset($link2))

@else
<div class="links-cats-wrap">
<div class="links-cats-img"><img src="images/links/{{ $link->img2 }}"> </div>
<div class="links-cats-link">{{ $link->link2 }}</div>
<div class="links-cats-desc">{{ $link->desc2 }}</div>
</div>
@endif

@endforeach

 @stop
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish in your template. You should be able to use `@if($link3 == "")` in blade just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the if statment to

```
@if($link->link3 != "" )
```

now works perfectly